# how to consume topic without group id in spring for @KafkaListner

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to disable group id based. or i want to give random group name for each instances.

I tried

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.MY_TOPIC)
public void consume(ConfigData configData) {
    try {
        config.add(configData, null);
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

```java
//service in groupId is same class  
@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.MY_TOPIC,groupId = "#{T(service).getDefenderGroup()}")
public void consume(ConfigData configData) {
    try {
        config.add(configData, null);
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

I have tried both of them but am getting same exception for both code as following

```java
(SpringApplication.java:843) - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No group.id found in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener annotation; a group.id is required when group management is used.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how Apache Kafka works. When you subscribe to the specific topic (`topics = Constants.MY_TOPIC`), the `group.id` is required.

So, if you don't go the manual partition assignment, you have to specify a `groupId` option. Right, it can be something random, but then we need to understand what that your `#{T(service).getDefenderGroup()}` SpEL does. The `T` operator is for types therefore use the fully qualified class name there and make sure your `getDefenderGroup()` is `static`.